# Looking for author of calculus quote

Tags: soft-question, differential-calculus

When I was  a lowly calculus student many many years ago, my calculus teacher quoted some famous mathemtician: "Calculus is the last course in arithmetic and the first course in mathematics that one takes."

Does anyone know the exact quote and the mathematican who said/wrote it.

Comment: I looked around, and I didn't find anything that matched your quotation. I'm wondering if your teacher made that phrase up himself, but thought it would sound better to his students if a "famous mathematician" said it.

Comment: Not an answer, I just wanted to express my strong disagreement with this opinion. It doesn't jibe with any of my experience taking or teaching calculus ...

Comment: Agree with @NikWeaver, this makes more sense for a *teacher* of mathematics who rates mathematical subjects by the challenges they present to the students than a working mathematician who usually doesn't rigidly separate mathematics into distinct subjects, let along rate them.